# Efficient Dynamic programming using Python

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I'm working on a dynamic programming task of finding a minimum cost path along a directed graph (all possible paths have the same number of weighted nodes).

The approach for solving the problem is a recursive function along with a dynamic programming.

Since this dynamic programming task is encountered in many unrelated problems during the code, the concept of threading could be helpful.

The problem is, that in python, '*threading*' won't help much.
what are efficient ways of handling such a task in python?

Here's the code:

```
    def rec_fun(pos, path_size, weights, directions):
        cost = weights[d][i, j]
        if path_size == 0:
            key = str(i) + ',' + str(j) + ',' + str(d)
            dict.update({key: pix_cost})
            return cost
        else:
            key = str(i) + ',' + str(j) + ',' + str(d)
            if key in dict:
                return dict[key]
            else:

                val = cost + min(rec_fun(pos + direction[0], path_size - 1, weights, direction),
                                 rec_fun(pos + direction[1], path_size - 1, weights, direction),
                                 rec_fun(pos + direction[2], path_size - 1, weights, direction))
                dict.update({key: val})
                return val
```

Comment: So... don't use threads? I don't see what prompted you to want to bring in threads in the first place. Dynamic programming doesn't require or even suggest the use of threads.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of dynamic programming to store the solutions to subproblems in memory to prevent redoing work?  A threaded approach is going to make that difficult.

Comment: @user2357112: that was just an idea for further improving the efficiency.

Comment: @Patrick Haugh: yes, that is the main idea. our problem is created from a lot of unrelated subproblems, each of them is solved using dynamic programming. that is why i made the threading remark.

Comment: Your approach could be rewritten using two for loops and no recursion. Then you will see why threading is not the way to go for further optimization. You may be thinking of running the cost calculation of the three directions in different threads, but that defeats the purpose of dynamic programing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first off, dynamic programming is just a simple paradigm for solving a certain type of problem. There is not really something specific you can do to optimize dynamic programming in general, in turn that means general python optimizations apply.

So from the code you posted the most striking thing I see is the use of recursions, this is relatively inefficient in python, so start off by moving to `for` (ideal) or `while` loops.

Following is a non-exhaustive list of possible ways to make your code run faster in python (with increasing effort):

1. Try [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) to speed your functions up significantly. It requires very little work (often the `@jit` decorator is enough) to optimize your code to almost cython level in some cases.
2. Make use of [Numpy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/) to vectorize your code where possible.
3. Use Processes `multiprocessing.Process` instead of Threads, as you probably already figured, python threads don't work the same way as in other programming languages due to the global interpreter lock. I think here it's important to note that sharing memory between processes is not really a good practice and you should avoid that if anyhow possible.
4. Use Python's C-Extension [Cython](http://cython.org/) to write all performance critical parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

With Python 3, you can easily achieve dynamic programming by caching the results of recursive calls using [lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) from *functools*.

You can wrap your function as such:

```
@functools.lru_cache(max_size=None)
def rec_fun(pos, path_size, weights, directions):
    # your code...
```

Note: Since this caches all calls so it could store more results than you necessarily need compared to implementing DP with your own array or list.